# How can I forget all .DS_STORE files in a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I'm working with a Mercurial repository in which .DS_STORE files are checked in. How can I forget those files (from all subdirectories)? *I see plenty of responses for Git,* but not Mercurial. I'd be immediately ignoring those files soon after, so if there's any way to do both, I'd love to hear about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you add the `.DS_STORE` entry to your [`.hgignore`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore) file, you can then forget all files that meet your ignore files with

```
hg forget "set:hgignore()"
```

Please note: **This will delete the files that you are about to forget!**

If you want to keep the files and just have them ignored by hg, I would copy the repo locally, `forget` the files, commit the `forget`ing, and copy back in those files you need around but not tracked.

`.hgignore` on its own has no impact on files that are already tracked.

Comment: > This will delete the files that you are about to forget!

Are you sure of this? help says: "it does not delete them from the working directory." (hg 2.9.2)

Comment: @ChristopheMuller: You're right in the sense that the files won't be deleted from the working copy where you issue `hg forget`. They will be deleted from other working copies when you `hg update` to the commit that remove them.

Comment: @MartinGeisler yes. Which is actually the desired behaviour :). Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.hgignore`. The syntax is similar to the one of `.gitignore`.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore

Comment: Unfortunately updating the `.hgignore` files won't _forget_ the files from source control since they have already been added in previous commits.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I misunderstood your question.